# How i control the height of columns in bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-ng-repeat

hey i am new in angular js and bootstrap.i use the col-md-4 and repeat this div until the data is get from json.i am using the accordian with some headings and drop down list. if the no of list is same in drop down then it shows fine result.

[image: Fine result]
if i extend the any list then it cause problem.

[image: Cause Problem]

Hope you got my problem.
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should split the `col-md-4` divs into rows, so that there's only three of them per row. Sort of like

```
<div ng-if"$index % 3 == 0" class="row">
 ... your panels code
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't extend the height since there is no data to fit it.

You could instead set a minimum height and if the div grows larger, you can do an in-div scrolling.

Something along the lines of:

```
.repeatingDivs {
    max-height : 50px; /* height of the smallest div */
    overflow-y : scroll;
}
```